# Executing a command from java code

Tags: java, maven, command, dos, processbuilder

Hi I want to execute this command from java code :

```
cd C:/Users/Amira/junoWorkspace/TestProjectUI
mvn -Dtest=MyClassTest.java test
```

So I found this method but i didn't find a way to adapt it to my case :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
            try
            {
                    // Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                   String[] cmd={"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe","/C start test.bat"};
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            // TODO code application logic here
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("echec de l'execution du script: "+e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
    }
```

Any idea ?
Cheers

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` doesn't always work (with all the commands).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which will allow you to set arguments like the working directory etc, it will also allow for multiple arguments, check [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ProcessBuilder.htm) and [ProcessBuilder Demo](http://0guzhan.blogspot.com/2011/01/process-builder-demo.html) for some examples on how to use it

Comment: and don't forget to handle the ErrorStream and the InputStream. 1+